# Deserializing JSON with numbers as key

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have JSON like this:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "method": "getTrades",
  "5183": {
    "buy_amount": "0.00455636",
    "buy_currency": "BTC"
  },
  "6962": {
    "buy_amount": "52.44700000",
    "buy_currency": "IOT"
  },
  "6963": {
    "buy_amount": "383.54300000",
    "buy_currency": "TNT"
  },
  "6964": {
    "buy_amount": "3412.50000000",
    "buy_currency": "FUN"
  },
  "6965": {
    "buy_amount": "539.45000000",
    "buy_currency": "XLM"
  }
}
```

I need to convert this JSON to domain model.

```
      public class Root {
       [JsonProperty("success")]
       public long Success { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("method")]
       public string Method { get; set; }
       public Dictionary<long, Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

      public class Transaction{
       [JsonProperty("buy_amount")]
       public decimal? BuyAmount { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("buy_currency")]
       public string BuyCurrency { get; set; }

      var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
```

I created these two models, but when I try to deserialize transactions, they are null. I got data for success and method

Comment: That's because all those JSON properties are on the same level as your `success` property, and not inside a `Transactions` property.

Comment: What should I change ? I don't want to create classes for all transactions.

Comment: One way would be to rewrite `Transactions` property to: `[JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, JToken> Transactions { get; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();`, but then you must convert each such pair afterwards. I don't know of any better way off the top of my head.

Comment: Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KtOkxJ

Answer (score 0):

Either the json needs to change, or you need to modify your c# structures. Not 100% sure, but based on the JSON, the c# class should be

```
public class Root : Dictionary<long, Transaction> {
   [JsonProperty("success")]
   public long Success { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("method")]
   public string Method { get; set; }
```

Comment: That won't work, because `success` is not a `Transaction`. Apparently it doesn't first check if there is a specific property it can store the value into, but instead tries to jam everything into the dictionary portion. I tried it, gives exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the JSON to something like this?

```
{
   "success": 1,
   "method": "getTrades",
   "transaction": [
      {
         "id": 5183,
         "buy_amount": "0.00455636",
         "buy_currency": "BTC"
      },
      {
         "id": 6962,
         "buy_amount": "52.44700000",
         "buy_currency": "IOT"
      },
      {
         "id": 6963,
         "buy_amount": "383.54300000",
         "buy_currency": "TNT"
      },
      {
         "id": 6964,
         "buy_amount": "3412.50000000",
         "buy_currency": "FUN"
      },
      {
         "id": 6965,
         "buy_amount": "539.45000000",
         "buy_currency": "XLM"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you could do something like that:

```
    public class Transaction    {
        public int id { get; set; } 
        public string buy_amount { get; set; } 
        public string buy_currency { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public int success { get; set; } 
        public string method { get; set; } 
        public List<Transaction> transaction { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: I know, but I can't change.
That JSON is response from some API.

Comment: Do all transactions come in the response always? Or depending on the case one or another might not come?